# "Write 'in' A4 sheet" or "Write 'on' A4 sheet"?

Tags: prepositions

If I want to instruct someone to use A4 sheets for doing assignments which of the following sentence would be grammatically correct?

> Write 'in' A4 sheet.

OR

> Write 'on' A4 sheet.

Comment: We write _in_ a  book, but _on_ a sheet of paper.

Comment: Any prior research?  This seems to be the sort of thing that is easily searched.

Comment: Also "sheet" is countable, so it needs to be "on **an** A4 sheet".

Comment: You might also say "write an A4 sheet" (or "write a side of A4") if you're explaining the length expected for the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say "Write on A4 paper" or "Use A4 paper".

"Write on A4 sheets" is possible, but not "Write on A4 sheet". ("Sheet" is a countable noun.)

Comment: "Write **in** A4 sheet." is okay?

Comment: No.  You could say "Write on an A4 sheet".

Answer (score 3):

We write **on** paper, and we would use an article:

> Write **on an** A4 sheet of paper (or **on a** sheet of A4 paper).

Comment: We'd only use an article if we expected the assignment to fit on a single page. Otherwise we'd use "paper" as a uncountable noun and no article: "Write on A4 paper."